# Wordpress indexing wp-content folder on Google

Tags: wordpress, indexing, permissions, directory, robots.txt

I recently got to know that one of the site I developed was not indexted in google, the URL is http://www.eziroll.com.au, so I searched google for site:eziroll.com.au and got a lot of URLs that end up in wp-content folder.

Index of /wp-content/plugins/ajax...
Index of /wp-content/plugins/custom-login-page
Index of /wp-content/plugins/wp-google-maps

Like this, please help.
Mac

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent folders from being crawled with the robots.txt file.

Something like:

```
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/cache/
Disallow: /wp-content/languages/
Disallow: /wp-content/themes/
Disallow: /wp-content/upgrade/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
```

Comment: This is what the robot.txt says
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/

Even if it allows to index the back-end it should index the front-end pages too right?